# OpenSSL key length too short in Ruby, not in Bash

Tags: ruby, bash, encryption

I originally experimented with a simple encryption script in Bash and it worked pretty much as expected. However, I'm now trying to do the same thing in Ruby and the Ruby version seems function a little differently.

## Bash

**Encrypt**

```
echo 'hello' | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a
```

Password: `mypass`

Result: `U2FsdGVkX19rERfOXiKs97FgwIkLy3+ttZzaHkEoQyE=`

**Decrypt**

```
echo 'U2FsdGVkX19rERfOXiKs97FgwIkLy3+ttZzaHkEoQyE=' | openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a
```

Password: `mypass`

Result: `hello`

---

## Ruby

```
require "openssl"
require 'base64'

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('AES-256-CBC').encrypt
cipher.key = 'mypass'
```

This is what I've attempted in Ruby so far but I receive a `OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError: key length too short` error. I would like to mimic Bash as much as possible.

Comment: The key is to short, you have chosen to use a 256-bit (32-byte) key `-aes-256-cb` but only supplied a 6-byte key `hello `. The Bash developers were just to lazy to flag the error but the error does exist. The Ruby developers were better and flagged the error. Provide the correct length key. There is also the issue of the IV which CBC requires but do not provide, check the documentation for how this is handled in each case. Also the Bash and/orRuby may be extending the password to a kay and may be creating a random IV and add it to the encrypted data.

Comment: Thanks that clears a lot of things up. I'm still new to encryption but for this particular use case I just want to have a single, memorable password as the key. Is it unadvised to pipe the encryption/decryption through the Bash version into Ruby?

Comment: The general solution is to create a key from a password with a password derivation function such as PBKDF2 (Rfc2898). As Maarten points out OpenSSL uses PBKDF2 by default, Ruby does not. But in any case the security is based on the "quality" of the password, functions such as PBKDF2 slow down brute force attacks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenSSL uses a (largely undocumented) password based key derivation function (PBKDF) called `EVP_BytesToKey` using an 8 byte salt and an iteration count of 1. A magic and salt of 8 bytes each are prefixed to the ciphertext (check the first bytes of the result to see the magic).

Obviously `"mypass"` cannot be a correct key for AES. AES keys are 16, 24 or 32 byte binary values for the 128, 192 and 256 key sizes. You can however specify a key directly using the `-K` switch on the command line to make the code compatible with the Ruby `Cipher` object. In that case you need to specify the key using binary (a file) or hexadecimals for the `openssl` command line and in Ruby. You would also need to specify an IV.

Alternatively you would have to find an `EVP_BytesToKey` implementation for Ruby, but note that this is an old OpenSSL specific function with a completely insecure iteration count.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into the `EVP_BytesToKey` for ruby implementation. Like I mentioned to @zaph I'm really looking for the best encryption that I can secure with a single password. Is there a better solution than `EVP_BytesToKey` that would meet that requirement?

Comment: Yes, there is PBKDF2 in OpenSSL including the Rubi API but I don't know if it is available from the command line. I think it isn't.